# Error: "could not be scrolled into view", wait_until_clickable doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium

I got a Python script that parses a website on Tor. It frequently encounters a Captcha and the driver is running in Headless mode so I can't fill the Captcha by myself. The Captcha looks like this:
[image: It's the DarkMarkert Captcha]

The idea I got was to screenshot the Captcha and enter the position of the pictures that need to be selected (1 to 15). I planned to do that using `driver.find_element_by_id` and iterate for each picture. But I got the error `could not be scrolled into view`. I tried to use the `wait_until_clickable` method but it didn't work.

After that, I tried to use `ActionChain` and moving to the element before clicking but this raised the error `rect is undefined` when trying to perform the moving action.

The piece of code doing that:

```py
    captcha = captcha.split(',')

    fenetre = browser.driver.find_element_by_id('capouter')
    actions = ActionChains(browser.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(fenetre)
    actions.perform()
    actions.reset_actions()

    for i in captcha:
        sleep(5)
        browser.driver.find_element_by_id("Cap"+str(i)).click()
```

I begin by splitting the string containing the positions (example 1,5,7). Then I move to the Captcha window because it makes it grow. I thought it was necessary to be able to click but it doesn't change anything. After that, I search for the checkbox by its id (Cap + the position on the image) and click it.

I don't know if you have a solution or a workaround to my problem. I post the HTLM code of the page in case you need it.

HTML code looks like that (too long to post):

```html
<html lang="en"><head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>Robot Check</title> 
<link id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64"> 
</head> 
<body> <style>
.capcheckbox{display:none}.select_all{white-space:pre-line;user-select:all}.capcheckbox+label{position:relative;height:60px;width:60px;display:block;transition:box-shadow .2s,border .2s;border:2px solid #ccc;cursor:pointer;border-radius:30px;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}.capcheckbox+label:hover{border:solid 4px #AF0E86;box-shadow:0 0 1px #AF0E86}.capcheckbox:checked+label{border:solid 4px #AF0E86;box-shadow:0 0 1px #AF0E86}.capcheckbox:checked+label:after{content:'\2713\0020';height:1em;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;margin:auto;color:#AF0E86;line-height:1;font-size:40px;font-weight:700;text-align:center}.captable{width:auto;margin:0  

[...]

</style><div class="jswarning"> 
<div class="jswarning_c"> 
<h4><span class="label label-warning">Warning !</span></h4> 
<span>Javascript is enabled. To continue, disable Javascript!</span> 
<p><small>- Type "about:config" in your address bar.<br> 
- Search for "javascript".<br> 
- Set "javscript.enabled" to "false".</small></p> 
</div> 
</div> 
<noscript> 
<style> 
.jswarning { display: none !important; } 
</style> 
</noscript> 
<div class="page-header"> 
<h2>&nbsp;</h2> 
</div> 
<div class="container cap-panel">

<div class="panel panel-info" id="capouter"> 
             <div class="panel-heading"> 
                <strong>Are you human ?</strong> 
             </div> 
             <div class="panel-body">
<form action="" method="post"> 
<div class="form-group">
<!-- gpgpub -->
<label>Select all images containing banknote(s)</label>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="captable">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="capcheckbox" id="Cap1" name="cap" value="1">
<label for="Cap1" style="background: url(data:image/png;base64, no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;"></label>

</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="capcheckbox" id="Cap2" name="cap" value="2">
<label for="Cap2" style="background: url(data:image/png;base64, no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%;"></label>

[image 3 to 15]

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Check"> 
</div>
</form> </div></div>
</div> 
 

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wait for 'element_to_be_located' instead of clickable.